Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user_name` on serializer `UserRegistrationSerializer`
I'm trying to create a custom user model with user role but when registering users i keep getting the same error
this is what i did
MY USER MODEL.PY
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    class RoleType(models.TextChoices):
        SCHOOL = 'SCHOOL'
        PARENT = 'PARENT'
    

    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=RoleType.choices, default=RoleType.SCHOOL)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user_name'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def tokens(self):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(self)
        return {
            'refresh': str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token)
        }

THE PARENT MODEL.PY
class Parent(models.Model):
    # other fields related to student ...
    Parental_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user", null=True)

THE SERIALIZER.PY
class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    RoleType = {
        'SCHOOL': 'SCHOOL',
        'PARENT' : 'PARENT'
    }

    role = serializers.ChoiceField( 
                                      choices=RoleType, default=RoleType['PARENT'])
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['user_name', 'password', 'email', 'role']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
            'email': {'required': True},
            'user_name': {'required': True}
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user



class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserRegistrationSerializer(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ['Parental_code', 'user']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = User.objects.create_user(**user_data)
        user = Parent.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        return user

MY VIEWS.PY
class UserRegistrationView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ParentSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        response_data = ParentSerializer(user).data
        return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

THE ERROR IM GETTING
i tried cheking the spellings but i havent fount any problems in that area
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\john\Desktop\POGONA_DATABASE\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\john\Desktop\POGONA_DATABASE\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\john\Desktop\POGONA_DATABASE\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\john\Desktop\POGONA_DATABASE\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\john\Desktop\POGONA_DATABASE\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\john\Desktop\POGONA_DATABASE\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\john\Desktop\POGONA_DATABASE\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\john\Desktop\POGONA_DATABASE\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\john\Desktop\POGONA_DATABASE\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 190, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\john\Desktop\ECHAKULA-01\ECHAKULA_WEB\customauth\views.py", line 20, in create
    response_data = UserRegistrationSerializer(user).data
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\john\Desktop\POGONA_DATABASE\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 555, in data
    ret = super().data
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\john\Desktop\POGONA_DATABASE\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 253, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\john\Desktop\POGONA_DATABASE\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 509, in to_representation
    attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\john\Desktop\POGONA_DATABASE\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 479, in get_attribute
    raise type(exc)(msg)
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `username` on serializer `UserRegistrationSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Parent` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Parent' object has no attribute 'username'.

im stuck and i'm in need of assistance, i think the problem is somewhere in the serializer or the models

Are you importing your custom user model correctly, not the default User  model.

Field User.user_name does not exist. Django contrib User model define the field username. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/auth/#fields

I've tried changing the field name to username but I'm still getting the same response

@johnkalala Are you getting the same error after using username too? Provide the Full error traceback.

@SunderamDubey i've added the full error traceback
